# How to get the return value of a method in a $.ajax (typ get) call?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC Application where I have a method, which returns a list of Objects:

```
public List<FileObject> GetAllFilesFromDirectory()
        {
            string filePath = @"C:\FilesToWatch";
            string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            FileObject fo;

            List<FileObject> list = new List<FileObject>();

            foreach (var file in fileEntries)
            {
                FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);

                fo = new FileObject
                {
                    FileName = info.Name,  //asdf.txt
                    FilePath = info.FullName //C:\FilesToWatch\asdf.txt
                };

                list.Add(fo);
            }
            return list;
        }
```

Now I want to return this list in javascript:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Home/GetAllFilesFromDirectory",
            data: ???,
            success: function () {
                console.log('success');

            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('error');

            },
            complete: function (data) {
                console.log('complete');

            }
        });
```

I know, that I have to add the `data:` attribute, but I do not really know, what I should write after `data:` to return this list.

Comment: first off remove the data from the get request it has no need.
then in the success function type Console.log(data); so that u can view the returned object  in the chrome console or any other browser

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada In my firefox browser I get "Error data not defined"

Comment: @IbraHimM.Nada I have already found the solution, I forget to give success: function() the data parameter, now it works, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to pass `data` as your controllerAction accepting no arguments. Here is more clear result you can return from your controllerAction  as follow:

```
  public ActionResult GetAllFilesFromDirectory()
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\FilesToWatch";
        string[] fileEntries = Directory.GetFiles(filePath, "*.txt", 
       SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        FileObject fo;

        List<FileObject> list = new List<FileObject>();

        foreach (var file in fileEntries)
        {
            FileInfo info = new FileInfo(file);

            fo = new FileObject
            {
                FileName = info.Name,  //asdf.txt
                FilePath = info.FullName //C:\FilesToWatch\asdf.txt
            };

            list.Add(fo);
        }
        return Json(new { filesList = list }, JsonRequestBehaviour.AllowGet);
    }
```

And then you can read the response in ajax as follow:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "Home/GetAllFilesFromDirectory",
        success: function (resp) {

          if(resp.filesList)
          {
              $.each(function( index, element ) {
                     console.log(element.FileName ); // i.e log the file name 
             });
          }


        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('error');

        },
        complete: function (data) {
            console.log('complete');

        }
    });
```

Comment: i cannot use JsonRequestBehaviour, it is red underlined

Comment: @FlorianHaberfellner make sure you have the namespace `System.Web.Mvc`